# Android: How to hide the Status/Action Bar but keep the notification bar

Tags: android, tabs, notifications

So in my app I like the way that the user is able to see the notification bar. However, I want to hide the Action Bar that says what the title of the activity is. If I make a regular activity, they are both hidden.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the action bar by changing the theme from the `styles.xml` file
to something that says `NoActionBar` at the end like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
```

or you can do it dynamically in java code for a specific activity in your app:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```